# Elasticsearch implementing sort by field and direction

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've been reading the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html) and other example posts since yesterday to work out how to add **sort by field** and the **direction** to [my current query array here](http://pastebin.com/wym1AKvE) but so far no luck. I've seen examples like `{"sort": {"_score": "desc"}, "query": { ....` but couldn't quiet get my head around it to modify my array since this is the very first time I'm dealing with ES.

All I need is: I want to be able to sort by `price` or `stock` in `asc` or `desc` order.

Everytime I try to update my array to implement sorting, I get `{"error":{"code":0,"message":"Invalid option sort"}}` error.

NOTE: The query array is being passed to [Pagerfanta](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta) to get results.

```
    $paginator = $this->productFinder->findPaginated($myArray)
        ->setMaxPerPage($limit)
        ->setCurrentPage($page);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific field and direction:

```
{
   "sort": {
      "price": "asc"
   }
   ... rest of the code
}
```

For no particular sorting (this is set by default):

```
{
   "sort": {
      "_score": "desc"
   }
   ... rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
{
  "_source":true,
  "query":{
    "simple_query_string":{
      "query":"1*"
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "price":{
        "order":"desc",
        "missing":"_last"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score":{
        "order":"desc",
        "missing":"_last"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I updated my original query array according to your suggestion and ended up with [this one](http://pastebin.com/XFhNdebT) but didn't touch `query` section because it is needed. As a result, I don't see any change in order.

Comment: And what happens when you change the order to "asc"? Have you tried to play with these settings?

Comment: I played with the settings but nothing seems to be changing. Result is intact.